# List splicing in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I want to create a procedure called `(splice L i n A)` where `L` is a list, `i` is an index, `n` is the number of elements and `A` is another list. So `i` is the index at which I would like to insert the list `A` into the list `L` and `n` is the number of elements that I want to remove from my new list starting at index `i`.

For example:
if I run

```
(splice '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 1 '(a b c))
```

this will give me

```
(1 2 a b c 4 5)
```

so I added the list `'(a b c)` at index `i` and I removed 1 element starting at index `i` which would be the 3.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Is this homework?

Comment: I am able to splice the list A into the list L at the index i but I don't know how to remove n number of elements from the original list starting at i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution `split` accepts a continuation `k`, which takes the left and right part of the list `L`.

```
(define (split L i k)
  (let loop ((left '())
             (right L)
             (i i))
    (if (> i 0)
        (loop (cons (car right) left)
              (cdr right)
              (- i 1))
        (k (reverse left) right))))

;; (split '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 (lambda x x)) => ((1 2) (3 4 5))
```

How to removing the initial elements of a list should be obvious.

```
(define (chop L n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (chop (cdr L) (- n 1))
      L))

;; (chop '(3 4 5) 1) => (4 5)
```

And how to put the two functions together should be easy, too. `split` takes the continuation, which gets the left and right part. And the continuation appends to the left part the list `A` and then the remaining elements of the right part.

```
(define (splice L i n A)
  (split L i
         (lambda (left right)
           (append left A (chop right n)))))

;; (splice '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 1 '(a b c)) => (1 2 a b c 4 5)
```